# Would a 'World Tree' be feasible in real life?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, creature-design, physics, hard-science

A [livescience.com article](http://www.livescience.com/14667-tall-trees-grow.html) claims that trees can reach a theoretical height of 400 to 426 feet (122 to 130m). This is due to the tree being unable to carry water up to the top at that certain point due to gravity. It also claims that

> at a certain height, leaves (or, in the case of redwoods, needles) are not cost-effective — the energy they rein in through photosynthesis doesn't pay for the energy it costs to bring them water

I'm interested in designing a tree that's much taller than 130 meters. Specifically, I'm interested in creating a titanic "world tree" that exceeds the theoretical height limit. The world tree would have a ludicrous amount of leaves for photosynthesis.

[image: world tree]

Provided the perfect conditions for growth, what methods could the tree use to ferry the water upwards? And what would the limit be in that case? I'm assuming that there are other factors that could limit tree growth besides the inability to ferry water to the top of the tree; for example, after a certain height the wood of the tree may collapse on itself.

To be slightly clearer, I would like a list of evolutions/adaptations that would allow this tree to exist under perfect conditions and stability and what its height limit would be in that case. I can understand that such a tree with conventional earth trees impossible, that the limitations of wood would debilitate its height, and that it would not go over the troposphere due to temperature and air conditions

Thanks for the answers,tho I don't think I'll be messing with the gravity

Thanks to Brythan and Hamlet for the edits :D

---

**N.B.** Read the requirements for the [hard-science](/questions/tagged/hard-science) tag before answering!

Comment: With the physiology of the plants of Earth, no. But an alien tree could perhaps evolve a heart, which would increast the height it can take water to. Alternatively the tree could grow horizontally instead of vertically and take over the world.

Comment: A planet mad of wood, would it not be like a snake in that case? Eventually it would curl up so many times that it kills itself I think as the surface area of leaves won't be able to support that stupid amount of volume when there are more than one layer of tree XD

Comment: I can think of a way, but how high are you thinking?

Comment: As high as it can reach until wood can't take it anymore? We don't see wooden skyscrapers do we?

Comment: I can't do the math but here are sources that can help someone figure it out site 1: http://gizmodo.com/5965451/how-tall-can-a-lego-tower-be-before-it-crushes-itself site 2: http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/wood-beams-strength-d_1480.html site 3: http://www.simetric.co.uk/si_wood.htm   My guess is around 4 to 5 km

Comment: I imagine you could make any number of changes to other details of your world to make a tree grow to any arbitrary height. Can't draw water that high thanks to gravity? Decrease gravity. Can't get air that high? Thicken the atmosphere.

Comment: It would probably make more sense as a lichen- or coral-like colonial organism that resembles a tree.

Comment: What if the structure of the tree was different than other trees and instead of gather the water at the roots it gathered water in the air or collected it in pools within the branches? Then you could have a gravity pump, much like what you see in sky scrapers. The issue of energy would still exist, possibly, as well as any reaction necessary to heal if the tree were injured, but this would solve your theoretical gravity issues.

Comment: You may be interested in an idea Dan Simmons wrote about in the last book of the Hyperion saga. Aliens grew a tree ring around a star. In a low gravity situation, with no real "up" to pull water to, maybe the maximum height you describe could be exceeded.

Comment: With all this talk about water, who is to say that the alien tree needs water to live?  Why can it not be some other substance that it needs to sustain itself that is readily available from the atmosphere that is can pull in through it alien bark, leaves or some other alien attachment.  Since this would be an alien world where other have already stated you can change gravity, could you also not change the alien wood of the tree to be something stronger?  How close does the alien tree have to be to an earth tree?

Comment: I highly recommend that you read the novella *The Son of the Tree* by Jack Vance. It also has a world tree. Its feeding patterns may be...instructive (if the tree gets its food from unexpected sources, in a parasitic and/or symbiotic manner, it will have access to more and different resources than a normal tree).

Comment: From an evolutionary standpoint, the first thing I wonder seeing that picture is *why* would the tree become so high. It would be much easier for the tree to simply have a much shorter stem (basically be a forest at ground level). Now if there were other similar trees beside it that it had to compete with...

Comment: There is another problem that noone seems to have considered yet... Trees are top heavy, especially the one shown in the image. The leaf section is almost always has a radius the same or greater length as the height of the tree for those types of trees. So if you make a 4km high tree you're also looking at a 8x8km tree top in most cases. I have no clue how you'd do that.

Comment: With a three this large, the ecology there will be highly varied and adapted to the environment. There will probably be multiple biospheres due to the height.

Comment: Also worth mentioning is The Long Cosmos by Pratchett and Baxter. Minor spoilers but there is a type of tree on a specific world that grows miles high. The trees utilizes hydrogen from electrolysis to create floating water balloons to carry water all the way up; The material of the tree itself also is infused with hydrogen so that it is super light. I haven't finished the book so there may be more details, but it might be interesting. It's also worth noting that it's book 4 in the series.

Comment: @Devsman - While he could reduce gravity or thicken the atmosphere, I don't think he can physically do both. The moon has a gravity around 1/6th that of earth (so it could support a tree up to 2500 ft? Still well below his goal), but the low gravity means that it can't hold onto a substantial atmosphere.

Comment: @Renan better than a heart - create a kind of symbiosis with some of the creatures that live in it, where they have to haul fluids up to the higher parts of the tree.

Comment: The problems may have been addressed in "Class Six Climb" (http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1648970.Class_Six_Climb)  a sci-fi novel about an expedition to climb a tree 4200m tall. (For my fellow Americans, that about 2.6 miles)

Comment: I didn't see this noted anywhere else on here - redwoods and certain other trees are actually able to absorb water from their leaves, which may help with the transport issue.  http://www.fs.fed.us/psw/publications/documents/psw_gtr238/psw_gtr238_273.pdf

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer to your question, but could be helpful to your end goal. You could make many other things smaller in relation to the tree including humans and animals.

Comment: You know what this question needs? An eagle at the top of the tree, a dragon at the bottom, and an evil squirrel messenger.

Comment: The size of the tree in the photograph, I think, would affect cloud formation around it. If it were shaped right, and were in the right climate zone on the planet, couldn't it gather much of its water from clouds that accumulate around it and/or pass-by, rather than transporting water all the way up the trunk? ...also how did this get revived? Why did it show up on the first page of my feed here?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Assuming you can fix the water problem using some of the other answers given, like having pools along the height of the tree, extracting water directly from passing clouds, etc., you will still have to deal with the tree crushing itself under its own weight. The following is an engineering kind of answer to the question.

## Short answer

The equation that determines the maximum height of the tree is:

$$H_\text{max} = \frac{\sigma_\text{allow}}{\rho g}$$

Where $H_\text{max}$ is the maximum height of the tree, $\sigma_\text{allow}$ is the compressive strength of the wood, $\rho$ is the density of the wood, and $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity on your planet.

What does this mean? Well, the tree's height is directly proportional to the strength of its wood, so if the tree evolved to have ultra-strong wood it could grow taller. It is inversely proportional to density and gravity, so if the tree evolved to have extremely lightweight wood it could grow taller (maybe it uses some metabolic process to make balloons of lighter-than-air gas to support its weight too? that would be cool). Finally, as was mentioned in another answer, the lower the gravity the taller the tree. Halving the gravity doubles the possible tree height.

Note that it doesn't matter how big the tree's base is, it will still crush itself as it gets taller. This falls out in the derivation below if you want proof.

## The math

Let's consider the simplifying assumptions that the tree has a constant cross-sectional area $A$ along its height (for example, a cylindrical tree would have $A=\frac{\pi}{4}D^2$ where $D$ is the diameter) and that we can ignore wind forces and things that could tip the tree over, focusing just on the compression experienced at the bottom of the tree.

The weight of the tree would be density × volume × acceleration due to gravity:

$$W = \rho V g = \rho A H g$$ (where $\rho$ is the density of the wood and $H$ is the height of the tree)

The ability of the tree to carry a load is described by its "compressive strength" which is basically the amount of "stress" the tree can take before breaking. Compressive stress at the base of the tree is the weight divided by the area of the base:

$$\sigma = \frac{W}{A}= \frac{\rho A H g}{A} = \rho H g$$

The area in the numerator and denominator cancels out. Now we can rearrange to find the maximum allowable height:

$H_\text{max} = \frac{\sigma_{allow}}{\rho g}$

## Example

An oak tree on Earth could grow to a max height of $691\ \mathrm m$, given a wood density of $600\ \mathrm{kg/m^3}$, a strength of $4\,070\,000\ \mathrm{N/m^2}$ and acceleration due to gravity of $9.81\ \mathrm{m/s}$:

$$H_\text{max} = \frac{4\,070\,000\ \mathrm{N/m^2}}{600\ \mathrm{kg/m^3}\times9.81\ \mathrm{m/s}} \approx 691\ \text{m}$$

Material property sources:
http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/wood-beams-strength-d_1480.html
http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/wood-density-d_40.html

---

## Edit: Additional information

As mentioned in other answers, there are additional factors limiting tree growth. [This paper](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v428/n6985/full/nature02417.html) from Nature describes the limiting factors in some detail. It mentions that the theoretical maximum water transport height may not be reachable because as the pressure drops it can lead to embolisms within the xylem, which can cause nearby branches to die. Trees can try to mitigate this risk by reducing the size of their stomata, but that also decreases photosynthesis, meaning the top of the tree has a much harder time generating nutrients. According to their estimates, this limits the maximum height of trees on Earth to somewhere around 130 m.

Comment: Per [dotancohen's answer](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/48448/10342), halving the gravity allows for 4 times the height. This means your first formula should have $g^2$ instead of $g$ in the denominator. I haven't examined how this affects your other formulae.

Comment: "*the tree's height is directly proportional to the strength of its wood, so if the tree evolved to have ultra-strong wood it could grow taller*" The reasonable way to do this would be for the Tree to produce polymers, carbon fibers or even carbon nanotubes incorporated into its cellulose.  They are all made of carbon so there is no good reason why the complex organic processes of a living being could not be adapted to produce them.  These could conceivably give strength increases of 100-1000x, resulting in a Tree of 100KM or more.

Comment: @DanHenderson I respectfully disagree. The weight of the tree is mass times acceleration, a well known formula in physics. If you follow the rest of the small derivation, you will find that the weight is not squared at any point, therefore the height does not scale quadratically **according to the assumptions I have made**. I have given a detailed description of my assumptions, I don't know what dotancohen's assumptions were that led to $g^2$

Comment: @RBarryYoung Good suggestion with the nanotubes and polymers, however the analysis I used looked at compressive strength at the base of the tree. Nanotubes have fantastic tensile strength (i.e. you can pull on them really hard) but not as great compressive strength (if you push on them they tend to buckle, so you have to brace them together somehow). I think you'd be better off with a diamond base for the tree (opening up some worldbuilding possibilities of greedy miners risking collapse of the tree :) )

Comment: @BarbalatsDilemma I think I figured it out - I believe dotancohen's calculation is based not on compressive strength, but on the ability to draw water up, which may be quadratically proportional to gravity. I checked your maths and found that for what you're evaluating, it is indeed a direct proportion. My mistake!

Comment: You say the size of the base doesn't matter. But what if the tree is a flattish cone or pyramid? Wouldn't that help to distribute the pressure somewhat and reduce compressive forced at the base?

Comment: @Cerberus you are right that would have an effect, however using a cone or pyramidal shape introduces extra parameters that would be difficult to estimate. I assumed a cylindrical tree to allow for a very simple, straightforward and intuitive result. If the tree tapers off as it gets taller that would allow it to get taller

Comment: @BarbalatsDilemma So max height of oak is 694m tall but oak trees only grow to about 44 m tall? What does this mean?

Comment: @Sky It means that something other than the strength of the wood limits the growth of the tree. As stated in other answers, things like getting water to the top, actually having sufficient nutrients in the surrounding soil (a tree can't grow without food, and it competes with all the other trees in the forest, more or less), and its natural lifespan will limit its growth. My answer is entirely based on how tall a tree could get before it crushes itself, assuming those other problems have been solved

Comment: @Sky I added some more info on the other limiting factors in my answer, I hope that clarifies things :)

Comment: @BarbalatsDilemma Thanks, tho at this rate I'll be better off with magic :D

Comment: @Sky [Any sufficiently advanced technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws)...

Comment: @BarbalatsDilemma :P

Comment: Why does a world tree have to be made of anything recognizable as wood?  A bioengineered world tree could have carbyne-reinforced cell walls.

Comment: Couldn't it get even higher if the tree were hollowed? Also, how wide would it be?

Comment: @AlbertMasclans Based on the math, it doesn't matter if the tree is hollow. In fact, if its cross-sectional area is constant along its height, the tree can have any cross-section shape: circle, triangle, square, octagon, ring, anything. As for its width, the width has no effect on its ability to be taller (unless you consider bending/wind forces, which I do not). A wider tree would be stronger, but also heavier by the same proportion, so the tree gains nothing by being wider.

Comment: @AlbertMasclans I have edited the answer to make the independence on cross-section shape and size more clear, I hope that helps

Comment: Buoyancy from a thicker atmosphere would increase the maximum height, since the effective density would be lower. I haven't done the math to see how much difference that makes, probably close to none for anything but already very low density wood.

Answer (score 92):

**Water Basins**
If every 300ft or so the tree grew water basins to catch rain, (or maybe as a place to deposit water that it had already pulled up from below?) the higher parts could draw from these basins instead of directly from the ground.

This can also lend itself to the fertilization as well. If these basins were large enough they could become small ponds or lakes that could support life. The animals/plants/fungi/whatever that migrate, live, and eventually die there could become the primary source of nutrition for the world tree.

The limiting factor would come down to how high can you stack wood before the bottom most block is crushed by the weight. Because this is an alien(magic?) world you could always say as the tree grows old instead of outright dying, it carbonizes into some carbon fiber structure that allows it to withstand the immense weight of itself?

Comment: You got it typed up before me ^.^ there are questions how much water would be needed in the basin and the strength of the tree, but supposing you could build basins that could hold and a tree could withstand the various issues with tall structures there should be no problem.

Comment: Water basins are an amazing idea, I can actually see waterfalls from multiple basins and stuff. Thumbs up for you.

Comment: The water basins will only fill with water if they are below the level where clouds form AND the temperature is above freezing. Max cloud height is 6000 metres and those are not rain clouds. Above a certain height the water basins will be filled with ice and snow. If you really want your tree sticking beyond the clouds into the upper atmosphere (as in your picture) you need another method to get water above 6000m.

Comment: doesn't this mean that water will freeze in its xylem? So it's limit is slightly less than 6 km?

Comment: I think a 5km tall tree is plenty tall, even for a world tree! Also, is there any reason a tree wouldn't be able to take up metals through its roots and integrate it with tree to improve structural integrity?

Comment: Wolverine tree?

Comment: @Dent7777 I wonder if it would be more efficient to use birds to transport minerals. Sufficiently large colonies living in the water basins could range to the forest floor to forage for fruit, from which they'd deposit nutrients higher up on the tree in the form of their waste products.

Comment: @ckersch I was thinking about using some sort of soil bacteria or fungi to introduce iron into the tree through the roots much like they process and introduce nitrates.

With birds that feed on fruit would be getting their nutrients from other trees, which would have no more iron than the existing tree. If they were getting nutrients from a metal-rich source, that would certainly help. I think they would be important for getting nutrients further up the tree, not just metals.

Comment: I like "carbonizes into some carbon fiber structure", with 'fiber' being most appropriate for a tree - but at this size, it might need to be carbon nano-tubes, with a root structure that spans an entire tectonic plate..

Comment: "The limiting factor would come down to how high can you stack wood before the bottom most **block**" - i'd like to add that if you are using wood blocks, then the highest stack is 255, minus what bedrock you have beneath.

Comment: @Mindwin It's okay, reality has Cubic Chunks installed.

Comment: @DrBob But this doesn't have to be a planet with the same atmosphere as earth, does it? Perhaps this atmosphere is bigger, warmer, and moister? And you could decrease gravity.

Comment: This would have been my answer for the immediate water issue. However rain may not be enough to fill the basins. Perhaps the tree could be a natural condenser collecting moisture from the air. e.g. some parts colder than the air or some form of desiccant and process to extract the water.

Comment: @DrBob Max cloud height is much higher than 6000 m.  Clouds contain liquid water down to -40°C, which is pretty high up.  Why would the clouds have to be liquid?  Trees survive just fine in cold winters.

Comment: @gerrit. It has to be liquid for the water basin idea to work. Trees pump water, not ice. Also, photosynthesis shuts down below about 5 centigrade (bit less that that in arctic and alpine adapted plants). So you'd want your leaves to be down in the nice warm altitudes, not sticking out into cold, cold space.

Comment: The tree would develop thermogenesis (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermogenic_plants) around its basins. Either the plant itself produces a small amount of heat or it develops a symbiotic relationship with bacteria that will do that job. These bacteria will, of course, need energy as well. They could get it from the decomposing life that visits - or lives on the basin.

Comment: (cont.) All together, the basin ecosystem would keep generating some warmth as long and it stayed healthy. Birds and bugs would need to keep flying up and down the tree to get more food though. They would probably not do that every day, but over the course of their life like salmons.

Comment: So in other words... the tree becomes the world. Ecosystems nesting all over it. A true world tree.

Answer (score 24):

- **Transport :** Due to transpiration, water can go upwards in trees, however after a certain height the pressure won't be enough. **A way to counter this would be if the tree had a heart of some sort to act as a pump. *Also, the tree can absorb water from outside, so the leaves at the very top can still receive water.*** ( You can also decrease gravity in that world.)
- **Lifespan :** It will take a really long time for a tree to grow to that height, it can't be done if it lives only for 30 years. So the tree would have to be pretty much immortal **and** fast-growing, because even 3000 years is too little. **A way around this would be a tree whose offspring grow from itself (it is self-fertilizing, and the seed remains in the tree). So the tree will continue growing.**
- **Nutrition :** A tree that big needs lot of minerals. Which is hard to get if it's stuck in one place. **A counter would be if there were bacteria that excrete the minerals required for the tree, and also depend on the tree in some way. *Also it can have some sort of 'basins' which emits a scent that attracts bugs. The bugs fall in and are dissolved to provide the nutrition.***

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43073/discussion-on-answer-by-king-of-snakes-would-a-world-tree-be-feasible-in-real). Additionally, **keep it civil**. Several users made impolite remarks; insults have no place on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @HDE226868 : Well I didn't start it :)  (though I did continue it). Hey, why do I have this warning --> "Some of the information contained in this post ..." ? The stuff I posted does not really require links to wiki.

Comment: See the comments [here](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/48628/627).

Comment: @HDE226868 : I see. However what part of my answer requires additional info? Because the counters I gave, don't exist in real life. So I can't link it to anything.

Comment: Well, you could start with citing something for your lifespan numbers (i.e. why 30 and 3,000 years aren't enough); that likely has a foundation somewhere in basic biology. You could also back up your statement about water traveling through trees, as well as how you think a "heart" could work.

Comment: @HDE226868 : Oh, alright, then give me some time ( can't do it right now)

Answer (score 10):

If you significantly relax your concept of "tree", then consider this: an enormous buoyant "crown", attached to the surface via a long, lightweight, flexible "trunk".  On a planet like Venus, with its very dense CO2 atmosphere, there are a variety of gases that could provide the necessary buoyancy.

One gas that comes to mind - oxygen!  It [has a lower molar mass than CO2](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/8135/14337) and, as a bonus, is a natural product of photosynthesis.  The tree could start out growing on the ground, and then grow out some kind of bladder that captures the oxygen produced by photosynthesis.  As the tree grows older, both the stalk and bladder grow, lifting it higher into the atmosphere.

For water, your atmosphere could have a reasonable water vapor content - not so high as to make the atmosphere lighter than the gas bladders, but enough that your "trees" can extract the water they need directly from the atmosphere.  If your atmosphere is fairly well-stratified, the denser CO2 would sink to the bottom where it can provide more support, while the lighter water vapor would rise to the top, where your crown/bladder apparatus can extract it.  This would give a double-incentive for trees to grow as tall as possible - more light **and** more water the higher up you go.  The limiting factor would be at the point where the atmosphere no longer has sufficient density.

### Potential problems

#### Gravity

You may need to play with the mass of your world such that the buoyant forces are enough to overcome gravity.

#### Respiration

Plants need to respire just like the rest of us - this means consuming oxygen.  They could consume some of the O2 they've stored in their flotation bladder(s).  They might start to slump a bit at night, when at peak metabolic rate ;-)

Comment: And these bladders could contain valuable gases, which are harvested by humans. If the bladders should go low on gas...

Answer (score 9):

The tree's [ability to lift water](http://science.howstuffworks.com/life/botany/tree-grow.htm) would scale quadratically if the gravity of the planet were lower. Thus, on a hypothetical planet with **half Earth gravity (`g = 5 m/s^2`)** the tree could attain a height **four times as it would on Earth**.

If your planet had the Moon's gravity, for instance, the tree could reach a height of **four kilometers** high.

Note that BarbalatsDilemma mentions in [her answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/48435/would-a-world-tree-be-feasible-in-real-life/48470#48470) that once we remove the limit of water transport, the limiting factor of tree growth will become the wood's ability to withstand compressive stress, which increases linearly with height. **In fact, the strongest woods are from those trees which grow the tallest.** Therefore once the water transport limitation is removed, the tree may have reason to develop yet stronger woods.

To address concerns of lesser gravity affecting the planet's atmosphere, I present [Titan, a moon of Saturn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_(moon)). This moon has an **atmosphere thicker than Earth's atmosphere**. To address arguments that the atmosphere may be possible only due to the lower temperate at Titan's location, the leading theory of the origin of Titan's atmosphere is that it is caused due to low silicate content in Titan's crust, so *everything* is volatile. Thus, a higher temperature would actually increase the sublimation rate and *thicken* Titan's atmosphere. The higher temperature would expand the atmosphere, but so long as that atmosphere remains inside Titan's Hill sphere it would remain and cause even higher pressures. Titan's Hill sphere is about 50,000 KM, current atmosphere reaches about 1000 KM above it's surface, and volume increases by the third power with increasing radius. Note that these volatiles are organic materials, in particular hydrocarbons, so they would actually support plant growth very well.

Comment: Doesn't work. decreasing gravity decreases the amount of atmosphere which decreases temperature which decreases the height possible.

Comment: @Durakken: Not necessarily. See [Titan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_(moon)), Saturn's moon with gravity comparable to the Moon yet an atmosphere thicker than Earth's.

Comment: it's also got a much lower temperature.

Comment: @Durakken: Titan's lower temperature is generally accepted to be due to its distance from the Sun, not due to its gravity. Temperature and distance from the Sun are very strongly correlated in stellar systems, at least as supported by observations in our own solar system.

Comment: The reason there is a thicker atmosphere is due to the coldness of the planet which is reduced from what it would have because it has less gravity. The reason the moon is as warm as it is has to do with orbiting Jupiter.

Comment: @Durakken: I think that you have 2010 on the brain, given the username and mention of Jupiter! Titan orbits Saturn (actually the original target of the franchise) and there is much contention regarding the origin, development, and sustenance of the atmosphere. Note that inner the moons of Jupiter _are_ considered to be warmed due to tidal flexing caused by Jupiter's gravity, but that is not the case with Saturn's Titan which is much further away from its host planet.

Comment: Are you sure about the quadratic relationship between gravity and height? [BarbalatsDilemma's answer](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/48470/10342) seems to indicate that it's a direct relationship instead, and the math checks out. Can you provide a reference for the quadratic relationship?

Comment: @DanHenderson: Thank you, I'll search for a reference for the relationship as I do not remember the details of deriving it myself. In the meantime I address in an edit BarbalatsDilemma's excellent answer, which addresses the compressive strength of wood whereas my answer addresses water transport. I've also clarified that point in the answer body, which should have been explicit from the beginning!

Comment: @dotancohen A conclusion from a comparison is only valid when the environmental conditions are identical. So, by this comparision: _"Titan, with gravity comparable to the Moon yet an atmosphere thicker than Earth's."_ you can't conclude this: _"gravity doesn't have a direct effect on atmoshpere thickness"_. Because the environmental condition _"temprature"_ is not identical.

Comment: The leading theory of the origin of Titan's atmosphere is that it is caused due to low silicate content in Titan's crust, so _everything_ is volatile. Thus, a higher temperature would actually _increase_ the sublimation rate and _thicken_ Titan's atmosphere. **The higher temperature would expand the atmosphere, but so long as that atmosphere remains inside Titan's Hill sphere it would remain and cause even higher pressures.** Titan's Hill sphere is about 50,000 KM, current atmosphere reaches about 1000 KM above it's surface, and volume increases by the third power with increasing radius.

Answer (score 8):

the tree can utilize some form of https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_water_generator which would allow it to collect water from air itself. It would get water directly from the clouds and water vapor itself. I guess the leaves can act as a net to allow water to condense and is then absorbed by the leaves itself.

With the help of Google,https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troposphere#Temperature

I highly doubt the tree can survive past 6000 km depending on where the tree is situated as temperatures would start decreasing drastically near the tropospause and air would get thin. As for the trees support and weight, I'm thinking that it would have to evolve a kind of multiple tree trunk that winds together? A trunk that twists together might be a better support for the lower part but it would straighten out as it gets higher to avoid even more weight pressing down. For the amount of leaves needed to support a massive tree, the branches would need extra strength by either supporting each branch by intertwining[might be disastrous if the bottom branches break] or by 'braiding the branches' which should increase the weight it can hold.

Otherwise, it might be a nice little cheat to have your tree be supported by a really really tall steep cliff[part mountain part tree]?

Comment: Alien trees 0_0 , I'm not sure about the winding and twisting part, Any experts?

Comment: Yes. I have heard that the tops of the redwoods on the California coast, for example, get their moisture from the air.

Answer (score 3):

**Symbiosys** Life forms like little insects and birds search protection in the tree, the tree get water from animals urine and from air umidity (using sponge like leaves).

**Primitive refrigeration** The leaves could have a shape like a double "u" that is great for converting wind energy into mechanical energy, the side effect of that is that wind get cooler, allowing condensation of water (even if in very small amout).

**Symbiosis II** Certain life forms could actually evolve to bring water to the tree and get in exchange small fruits, if the tree is that big it is likely it has a complex ecosystem  inside it wich would make the tree also a isolated system.

This is for getting water.

For getting instead great height instead we have more problems, the tree would have a shape that resembles a reversed cone (base on ground and vertex upside).

Wood is light but also weaker than iron, so the height maximum reachable (to avoid mechanical breaking of the tree) should be slightly above or below the highest buillding, so don't expect it to be higher than a kilometer, however you could partially cheat if the tree grows on the highest mountain in your world.

EDIT: since tag advocates are becoming increasingly boring, here's for the hard-science part:

**Symbiosys:** no know micro-organisms have such a behaviour, however there's a spider that is able [to transfer air bubbles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diving_bell_spider) below water level to create a nest. Since there are already life forms that move air somewhere, it is plausible to assume are possible life forms that move water somewhere. Also, snails have a protective coating to avoid dehydratation when sleeping, the tree and its life forms could use a similiar mechanism to preserve water.

**Regarding the refrigeration:** simple physics law, if air do any work it spends energy in doing so and hence lower its temperature, [also certain shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pelton_wheel) (double "U") are really helpfull in  draining thermal energy and converting it in kinetic energy

Since a big life form is highgly susceptible to die by any disease (single DNA), it is more realistic if the tree is in reality a composite life form so that it has enough DNA variety to not die entirely due to diseases. We have already proofs of this being possible (moss is in reality made by 2 different life forms cooperating), also it is possible to do vegetable grafting (put a plant branch to a foreign plant to obtain new type of fruits), another proof that a vegetable life form wich is in reality made by different life forms is entirely possible.

Comment: Upvoted for first suggestion of symbiosis I've seen.  Don't overlook the possibility of multi-party symbiosis (as in the lichen, which was recently discovered to consist of two type of of fungi and an algae), and even a designed symbiotic relationship.  If you could design a lichen-like tree, that would grow horizontally as well as vertically, it could be an all-in-one terraforming juggernaut for an advanced society.  Think of "the creep" from Starcraft, but maybe more like the jungles of Kashykk (Star Wars)?

Comment: Then the sentients who designed the tree could care for things like water and nutrient delivery to the upper levels, and even pruning and reinforcement to enable the tree to exceed even its designed structural limits.

Comment: @SudoSedWinifred your comment deserve to be an answer, better THE answer, it is awesome your link with zergs :D

Answer (score 2):

Wind is a killer. There is a reason that the tallest trees have few branches below their crown. Catchment basins would act like sails and tear the tree apart. Sorry to rain on your parade. The highest building in the world is 830 meters tall and I doubt that mother nature could do more than double that with a living organism, but I'm just guessing...

Comment: you're missing the fact that theoretically the planet could have very little or no wind.

Answer (score 2):

Just passing through and thought I'd leave my thoughts on this topic...

Have a look at the latest (last) book in Terry Pratchett and Steven Baxter's Long Earth series, "The Long Cosmos". One of the worlds there has ginormous trees. Water transpiration to the upper branches is effected by the trees capturing / generating hydrogen, and using this to float sacs of water up to the upper levels.

Of course, the wood of the trees were highly imflammable, being chock-a-block full of hydrogen. The existence of such a world and such curious trees was never reported, probably because any traveller who stepped in, and stayed long enough to note the size of the trees, probably stayed long enough to collect some wood and make a fire... BOOM!

Comment: XD. Might be best to stick with helium then

Answer (score 1):

No. As trees are today it is impossible. In trees water is drawn up the tree passively. To get the kind of heights your looking for the tree would have to pump it own water. I can't see how a tree could produce enough energy through photosynthesis to power an active method of water transportation at that height. Furthermore if the tree grew too high the air would be too thin for photosynthesis or respiration. In order to survive our tree would have to eat other plants for sufficient energy and would have to pump oxygen up to the top of the tree.

Comment: I'm pretty sure his tree would "work" for his story even if the technical internal structure is wildly different from real earth trees, as long as it has the general outward features/looks.

Comment: And then the one small answer that starts with "No."

Answer (score 1):

A smaller version is possible, especially if it is adapted for that sort of thing: It can have a very thick base and thinner at the top (so it won't break), and very long roots that are spread out (so it will get minerals).

If it is near a river, in a relatively windless area then it can grow to large heights. This solves the problem of nutrition (the waste in the water provides nutrition, as well the other stuff stated by [KingOfSnakes](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/48435/would-a-world-tree-be-feasible-in-real-life/48450#48450) and it can have a heart which provides additional pressure to draw the water to its leaves.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your definition of "tree".

First, there are multiple answers here that propose a heart--this doesn't overcome the problem that lifting the water costs more energy than the photosynthesis yields.  This means either we obtain the needed water directly from the atmosphere (which means a humid climate) or we need some radically different chemistry.  Since we want something tree-like lets start with photosynthesis--but the high energy molecules aren't sent down the tree, but only laterally to the trunk where they are converted to electricity.  The products are sent back out to the leaves to be combined again--you only need to lift for growth or leakage, not for energy production.

Now, we need a very strong tree--instead of wood lets figure a core of metal foam.  Once the roots find suitable ore deposits they grow a metal foam core in each trunk.  For the sake of strength you need multiple trunks with many cross connections.  Look at how antenna towers are built for how the tree has to do it.

As the tree gets big enough we can take some of the load off it.  The tree grows a transparent but airtight canopy over itself.  The leaves are inside this canopy.  The canopy acts like a greenhouse--the insides are warmer than the ambient air which is good as it gets cold up there and you have in effect a giant hot air balloon.  If it's big enough the only elements in compression are those holding out the waist of the bubble, the rest of it is all in tension and therefore much easier to support.

The tree needs to have full regeneration capability or else the ravages of time will kill it before it gets to the size of a world tree.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few options, some of which will just be additional notes on existing answers:

**1. Capillary Action**

Capillary action could possibly circumvent gravity - it already does on a small scale in all sorts of real world situations.  The basis for capillary action is surface properties and surface tension of fluids allowing them to rise (or fall) through extremely narrow channels.  A fountain pen is a great example of this.  If you take an empty fountain pen and rest the nib in an ink well, ink will slowly rise through the nib into the ink feed.

**2. Water Collection Basins**

A tree could have natural collection basins, akin to a [strawberry pot](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-RV5HmQFZWMs/TbTGRbqd7iI/AAAAAAAABLY/_ez9RQR4LX4/s1600/strawberry_pot.jpg).  This would allow the tree to naturally collect reserves of water anywhere along its surface.  This could even be done (through some twist of evolution) at each location where a branch meets the trunk.  Actually, I'm almost surprised there are no Earthly trees (as far as I know) that do this.  Or possibly it's leaves could be designed to funnel water into such a system.  [Hostas](http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/351577/318651596/stock-photo-wet-yellow-and-white-hosta-plant-with-waterdrops-in-garden-318651596.jpg) work like this on a much smaller scale - drawing water into the base of the plant.

**3. Atmosphere**

If your planet is not strictly Earth-like, and the tree is tall enough, a persistent or near-persistent vapor base (clouds) at or near the crown of the tree could provide ample water, especially if the tree had adapted structures that would help capture and channel water.  This could even be as simple as interestingly channeled bark-like structures trapping and condensing water from the vapor.

Comment: What kind of clarification does this need?  I understand the reality-check and hard science tags - but I also believe that atmosphere and capillary action are readily available for discovery (these are not esoteric science concepts or heavily difficult concepts).  Additionally, the tag may need to be moderated off of the question since it's difficult to provide "hard science" for a question that specifically states that Earthly principles need not apply.

Comment: Jesse - That was me. I added post notices to a number of these answers because the majority don't meet the stringent requirements of the [tag:hard-science] tag (see the tag wiki). Most don't even link elsewhere - much less to a source like the ones the tag wants, like a peer-reviewed paper. This is a short-term option I'm exploring while we try to work out the details [here](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3716/hard-science-reminder-on-answering?cb=1). I'm sorry for any inconvenience this caused, but I'm trying to see if adding the post notice will work.

Comment: @HDE226868 understood. That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks for understanding. I considered saying something public about it - and I think I wrote offhand something in chat earlier today - but I wanted to keep it low-key to see how many people saw the post notices on their answers and responded with good edits; I chose this question as a test case. I have my fingers crossed for good results.

Comment: I'll see what I can do. I would suggest that a post shouldn't have science-based and hard-science since the latter implies the former, but the former has looser restrictions. Also, based on some details of the question, I'm not sure the OP has a good case for hard-science as a tag.

Comment: Sorry, just realized it was reality-check and not science-based on this post. Oops!

Answer (score 0):

The tree could get "help" from other organisms, willy nilly. People could feed it (they'd need a motive). Or it could consume other plants. Then it could have access to more energy and different materials than a normal tree.

I highly recommend that you read the novella *The Son of the Tree* by Jack Vance. It also has a world tree. Its feeding patterns may be...instructive.

It could also do something with solar power in order to generate energy, either by heating water in basins through reflective leaves, or by using metals that catch light and convert it into electrical power. It may be far-fetched, but it could work in a novel.

---

Another idea is that the world tree could get it's nutrients from the waste products of animals that live on it.

Answer (score 0):

All other answers assume the tree is growing in a gravity well.  This need not be the case - however, other constraints will apply (read Niven's 'The Integral Trees').

There is also a question of scale.  A perfectly normal tree could be considered a 'world tree' by a *very very small* intelligent race.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in order to make the tree possible the tree would have to be constructed with genetically modified tissue vertically with an ascending team of 3D printers as if a spider wove its cloth upwards, and this would have as main objective to have a "living" To shelter human life like living in a biological skyscraper, I believe that with all current and future technologies and the most brilliant minds in engineering and design it would be possible to build a tree that could reach 40,000 feet, ok no :P.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding Peter! This questions asks for hard science, meaning that all answers to this question should be backed up by equations, empirical evidence, scientific papers, or other citations. Any answers that do not satisfy this requirement, like yours, might be removed if you don't edit your answer and add in scientific evidence to support it.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say world trees really could have existed on earth it would need immense water to sustain itself i think of natural pure and warm spring water under it that flows up under higher pressure created under ground aiding the tree to pump the water up higher into its self and to prevent it from crushing into its own weight parts of its stem/trunk and root system must have been crystallized by the pressure of its weight together with the minerals within the spring water as it grew over time (like some of that evidence is found in tree stumps/trunks on this site https://secretenergy.com/news/are-these-giant-prehistoric-trees/)

Answer (score 0):

After looking at all of the comments, this is my personal conclusion for the ultimate "world tree".

**Leaves with very short hairs.** These leaves would not only produce energy through photosynthesis but absorb water like roots, where the hairs act as root hairs. With slightly different physiology this is certainly possible.

**Location in a valley providing relative shelter from winds.** The tree would also be very thick at the bottom and get progressively thinner to avoid breaking.

**No more than 2000 meters (2 km) high to avoid constant, ultra-low temperatures, but still have a massive size.** This would also remove the need to make ridiculously strong wood or other, more complicated and/or unrealistic elements.

**Light but relatively strong wood.** The tree would also (as with most plants) have a high lignin content, from which it would somehow produce its own carbon fibre and implement it into its own structure in high quantities, greatly strengthening the tree to keep it from essentially imploding.

**Pools of water from interlocking branches and/or leaves above ground-level, drawing in critters and providing energy reserves if needs be.** Microbes, insects, small mammals, and other organisms would be attracted to the relative safety/shelter of the tree, and with water, they would be even more likely to wish to take up refuge there. They could provide minerals and other nutrients in the form of their waste, and could even form a stronger symbiotic relationship of some kind (use your imagination). The pools would also work as energy stores, where the water could be saved and then used by the water-absorbent leaves.

**Very thin channels in the tree.** Water and other nutrients could travel throughout the tree based simply on the behaviour of fluids in very small channels (see Jesse Williams’ response for a somewhat more detailed description).

**Large root system capable of bringing other nutrients and support/stability.**

**Multiple "trunks" winding together.** This would divvy out the trees own pressure more evenly, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a world tree would be impossible to make if the trunk is only composed of one part. But if we take into consideration some trees like the [Banyan](https://www.google.com/search?q=banyan%20tree&rlz=1C1CHZL_enIN837IN837&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6u5vKv97iAhWUbX0KHSn-Dh0Q_AUIECgB&biw=1280&bih=610#imgrc=DlklxY-9kyg2CM:), or much more known in our country as *balete*, I think it could grow to become a world tree, provided that it has sufficient nutrients to support it.

A banyan tree is really a small tree if it is alone. However, it makes multiple aerial roots. And these roots grow big until it becomes like it's mother trunk. Its aerial root system made it possible for it to become bigger and bigger without fearing of being toppled down by gravity.

So, that's it. If our world tree has multiple aerial roots, it can support itself and not fear the ferocious hand of gravity. And it will grow taller and taller, but it will expand more and more, taking up more space than we would like it to be.